# TMaskEdit for Date curious behaviour when enter mask char

Tags: delphi, vcl

I am using a mask edit to create a TDateTime component.

I use the following mask: !99/99/0000;1;_

It works fine save that if as the user enters the date they also type the date separator, if they are on the second section (ie the month or the day depending on your locale), the cursor jumps to the year section. If you are on the year section it beeps.

I have tried capturing the dateSeparator in keydown of the component and although I intercept it and set it to 0 it nevertheless jumps from the day/month section to the year section. I even try resetting the selstart after setting the key value to 0, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas as to how to overcome this behaviour would be appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using a `TDateEdit`?

Comment: @JerryDodge: What's a TDateEdit? It doesn't come in Berlin's VCL. Do you mean TDateTimePicker?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, that's what I meant. Apparently I was in FMX when I looked it up in the component palette. Either way, I'm sure you know what I was asking.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Sure, I did, as I said when I asked. :-)  The question is tagged VCL, and the poster might not have known what you meant.

Comment: So let me ask the correct question: Any particular reason why you're not using the existing date related controls in Delphi?

Comment: TDateTimePicker does not allow user to clear a date entry as far as I can ascertain ie blank dates are not permitted. I've always found this a pain and have written my own date edit in the past. I am now writing one with a drop down calendar, but it is such a pain.

Comment: `TDateTimePicker` does however have a `ShowCheckbox` and `Checked` property, which accomplishes the same. Or you could try some third-party controls, such as Jedi JVCL, for example.

Comment: The checkbox disables rather than clears and it is in my view a clumsy way to accomplish what should be native behaviour. In the end I derived a component from a TButtonedEdit And a TCalendar without a mask and allowed free text entry of the date with checks and balances. This seems to work well for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to my question, but I solved the issue by using OnKeyPress instead of OnKeyDown and inserting the following code:

```
if (key = FormatSettings.DateSeparator)  then
  key := #0;
```